# what is actual value of variable t of type size_t when it is assigned negative value?(can be unsigned int instead of size_t)

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks, unsigned-integer, size-t

Assigning **-1** to variable `t` of type `size_t` and checking it's equality with both **-1** and **4294967295** (**FFFFFFFF**, 2's compliment of **-1**; my system is **64 bit**;value may vary with system), then in both the cases, it returns **1** i.e. **true**.

Code is

```
int main(){
    unsigned int t = 10;
    cout<<"t = -1: "<<(t==-1);  //checks if t is -1
    cout<<"\nt = 4294967295: "<<(t==4294967295);   //checks if t is 4294967295
    cout<<"\nt: "<<t;    //printing actual value of t
    int p = t;    //typecasting it to int
    cout<<"\np: "<<p;    //printing value of p
}
```

Actual output is

```
t = -1: 1
t = 4294967295: 1
t: 4294967295
p: -1
```

returning `1` for both checks `(t==-1)` and `(t==4294697295)` but outputs `t = 4294697295` and outputs `p = -1`.
Is it that the variable **t** is holding two values i.e. **-1** and **4294697295**.
Which is definitely not the case.

Help needed.
**What is actually happening inside the system??**

Comment: Signed and unsigned integer types are different, and will be printed differently.

Comment: "*Is it that the variable t is holding two values*". No, this is not true. Turn on your compiler warnings - it will tell you that comparing signed and unsigned values is not a good idea.

Comment: Compiler warnings exist for a reason.  If the people who wrote the compiler you're using to convert your code into a runnable executable think what you're doing is dodgy enough for the compiler writers to take the extra effort to create a warning, you'd do well to actually heed the warnings and fix your dodgy code.

Comment: Sidenote: C++ defines clearly how conversion takes place (derived from C): Add maximum unsigned value + 1 to the signed negative number until it fits into the unsigned type. Actually, this conversion is a no-op with 2's complement, as signed and converted unsigned value have same bit representation. This definition dates back to the times when there (theoretically at least) existed systems with 1-complement and sign-magnitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing signed value to unsigned, the signed value is converted to unsigned before comparison. This is done during compilation. So `t==-1` becomes `t==4294967295u` and `t==4294967295` (signed integer literal) becomes `t==4294967295u`.

Reference: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv

> (1.5.3)
>   Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.

Comment: Just wanted to add: Cause of the behavior  was probably caused by OP ignoring compiler warnings.

Comment: `4294967295u` isn't equal to `10u` though.

Comment: Actually, the literal doesn't fit into an int (32 bit-int provided) – we'd need to add `L` suffix (64-bit Linux) or `LL` (other systems)...